# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in twig template with jQuery import

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have this code in my twig view:

```
{% extends "MyBundleBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="page-header">
        <h4>add an equipement</h4>
    </div
    <select id="selectEquipement">
          <option selected disabled>choose an equipement</option>
          <option value="{{ path('addEquipement1') }}">Equipement 1</option>
          <option value="{{ path('addEquipement2') }}">Equipement 2</option>
    </select>

    <div id="formEquipement"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#selectEquipement').change(function() {
                var url = $(this).val();
                $.get(url , {} , function(formulaire)  {
                    $("#formEquipement").html(formulaire);
                    })
                })
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When i load the page content of this view I have this error on the first line of my script `$(document).ready(function() {` :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in twig template

I understand that jQuery is not **load**. When I add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` this tag on this view, all works well, I have no error.

But, in fact I already import in my application (local) the **jquery script** I need. So In my main layout I have imported the script like this:

```
{% block script %}
                {% javascripts

                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/applydataTables.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.form.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.sumoselect.min.js'
                                '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js'
                                'http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.3/js/dataTables.responsive.js'%}
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
                {% endjavascripts %}
            {% endblock %}
```

Someone know why? I noticed that I have some errors like these since I **upgrade** my symfony application to the 2.6 version.

Moreover, when I use **Ajax** call in my application, in the **symfony toolbar**, the notification for Ajax request does not work like before (no notifications), but when I debug in the **network tab of my browser** all works well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729383/2025923

Comment: have you clear the cache and dump the assetic? not 404 error in browser debug network tab?

Comment: @ihsan, thank you for reply: no 404 error, the cache is already cleared and the assets are dumped.

Comment: @Tushar, as you can see in my code, in my main layout, I import jQuery first. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I guess there are two entries of jquery `@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js` and `@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.js`. Is it identical? What happen if you only use one?

Comment: @ihsan, I rectify the code, just a mistake when I copy the code, but in my real code, I have just `@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js`. Sorry. And the error is still here.

Comment: What happen if you use jQuery(...) instead of $(...)?

Comment: @ihsan, the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` occured if I use `jQuery(...) instead of $(...)`

Comment: Maybe your jquery file `@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js` is broken?

Comment: @ihsan, I remove the jquery.min, and I replace by another jQuery version (2.1.3), in order to see if indeed it was the jquery.min.js file was broken. But the same error occured. I replace the file, clear the cache and dump assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

with

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

`window.onload()` fires later than `document.ready()` when all elements, including the dynamically generated ones (or included) have been loaded.

**EDIT:** Can you try moving your code after the jQuery code, in the footer?

The right way to do it would be to have a separate .js file and call it in the footer, right after jQuery.

Comment: I alredy tried your suggestion, but I have the same error when I replace `$(document).ready(function() {` by `$(window).load(function() {`

Comment: Is jQuery loaded in the footer? And is your code loaded before or after that?

Comment: sorry for answer you just now. I load my script at the end of the html body, after my html code. It's the right way to load script no? I know that some developer load their script in the header tag. To answer at your 2nd question, my main layout is loaded before the template who extends the layout.

Comment: I know it should work, but can you try moving your code after the jQuery code, in the footer? The right way to do it would be to have a separate .js file and call it in the footer.

Comment: edit your answer in that way I can calid her, I move my script before the code and it works. Thank you a lot.